# The Vowel Eater

Tags: knowledge, english, quote

Here's a quote from a very famous book with all the vowels and punctuation removed. Can you re-assemble it?

> fyrbrnncbclndgrwpncrrdrndwrkncllndvctnncrwddsnrmthncmngpntthpnwthnthngbtskyvrymghtjstgvynrvsbrkdwn

Comment: Are you sure we need a new tag for this puzzle?

Comment: @IAmInPLS; i couldn't think of anything else

Comment: I think the tag "English" will be fine for this puzzle

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> "If you're born in a cubicle and grow up in a corridor, and work in a cell, and vacation in a crowded sun-room, then coming up into the open with nothing but sky over you might just give you a nervous breakdown."
>  *by [Isaac Asimov](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/477447-if-you-re-born-in-a-cubicle-and-grow-up-in)*

Comment: very good, and very quick! how did you guess?

Comment: It's difficult looking from the start, but the last two words are easy to get, and from there I looked for quotes.

Comment: Nice job! Great books those :)