# And the rest is hstr!

Tags: wordplay, english, history, quote

<sub>This is an entry in the [14th Fortnightly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/fortnightly-topic-challenge-14-history).</sub>

---

Ha, nice, a new fortnightly challenge. What's more, it is about history! It seems that people didn't like sports that much, huh? Fortunatly, there are 
(good) puzzlrs around here who seem to lke history. Like @Sleafr, who alredy postd two questins for ths challnge. Hey, what is that? I ment @Slefar,
of corse. No, [@Sleafar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15632/sleafar) * ! God dmmt, what's happnng with the vowls? It's lke I am a @JnMarkPrr [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40829/the-vowel-eater) No, t's [@JonMarkPerry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497/jon-mark-perry) * ! Argh, cm on I can't evn pzzle prprly, 
**th pnctutin s gong awy**! Sht I hv to do it fst: the goal f this puzzl is to **fnd the reltion betwn thse five famos quots**Findthir authrs, andyo'll fndth relatn!
 k, evnth spacsre vnishng... **Rmmbrths s taggd hstry**...

> whndplmcndswrbgns
>
> hstrwllbkndtmfrntndtwrtt
>
> dsrfrmrpwrflthngnswdntltrpplhvgnswhshldwltthmhvds
>
> thbttrgttknwmnthmrfndmslflvngdgs
>
> wcnntlwsbldthftrfrrthbtwcnbldrthfrthftr

---

<sub>* : I'd like to thank them by the way, they inspired me to make this puzzle.</sub>

Comment: nice puzzle for a good fortnightly challenge!

Comment: As a side note: According to Wikiquote the second quote is often [misattributed](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/History#Misattributed).

Comment: @Sleafar Interesting. Nonetheless, when we know the kind of man Churchill was, we can understand why the latter one is the most remembered :)

Comment: @IAmInPLS Does that invalidate your puzzle or what?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**The quotes are:**

1.

> *'When diplomacy ends, war begins'* - **Adolf Hitler**

2.

> *'History will be kind to me, for I intend to write it'* - **Winston Churchill**

3.

> *'Ideas are far more powerful than guns. We don't let our people have guns. Why should we let them have ideas?'* - **Joseph Stalin**

4.

> *'The better I get to know men, the more I find myself loving dogs'* - **Charles de Gaulle**

5.

> *'We cannot always build the future for our youth, but we can build our youth for the future'* - **Franklin D. Roosevelt**

They are all quotes from:

> **The leaders of powers in WWII (1939-45)**:
>
> Adolf Hitler - Leader of the Nazi Party and Chancellor of Germany (1933-45)
>
> Winston Churchill - Prime Minister of Great Britain (1940-45/51-55)
>
> Joseph Stalin - Leader of the Soviet Union (1920(s) -53)
>
> Charles de Gaulle - Leader of France (1940-44)
>
> Franklin D. Roosevelt - US President (1933-45)

Which is why it is part of the Fortnightly Topic Challenge

Comment: Since you guys already started an answer, Ill post number 4:  The better I get to know men, the more I find myself loving dogs." - Charles de Gaulle

Comment: number 5 :Franklin D. Roosevelt — 'We cannot always build a future for our youth, but we can always build our youth for the future

Comment: Not just from WWII, but from the leaders of some of the major countries involved in WWII.

Comment: @EngineerToast, good point

Comment: Your answer for 2 does not match the letters in the puzzle. "Because" should be "for".

Comment: 2 may instead be "History will be kind to my frontend tower tutu."

Comment: 3) should be "people" not "enemies" according to the puzzle anyway

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Listen to jdwhitfield ;) It is people indeed, and it makes more sense when you know who said it... I'll edit it out because the version of the quote I used is slightly different.

Comment: Anyway, this is it! You were fast :o I hope you still enjoyed this puzzle! Good job!

Comment: Thnks @IAmInPLS, rlly njyd th pzzl! :)

Answer (score 16):

Answer: Thanks to everyone as listed

First (Courtesy of @Beastly Gerbil) is:

> "When diplomacy ends, war begins." - Adolf Hitler

Second row is

> "History will be kind to me, for I intend to write it" - Winston Churchill

Line Three:

> "Ideas are far more powerful than guns. We don't let our people have guns. Why should we let them have ideas?" - Joseph Stalin

Line four (Courtesy of @Acerfire37):

> "The better I get to know men, the more I find myself loving dogs." - Charles deGaulle

Line five (Courtesy of @Juan Tomas):

> "We cannot always build the future for our youth, but we can build our youth for the future." -Franklin D. Roosevelt

Answer:
The relationship is

> These are quotes of leaders in WWII

Comment: Number 4 is  
 The better I get to know men, the more I find myself loving dogs." - Charles de Gaulle

Comment: Number 3 is "people" not "enemies" (at least in the puzzle)

Comment: Good job to you sir :). @jdwhitfield is write, it is people indeed. It makes more sense when you know who said it ;)...

Answer (score 11):

> When diplomacy ends, war begins.  (Adolf Hitler)

> History will be kind to me for I intend to write it.  (Winston Churchill)

> Ideas are far more powerful than guns. We don't let our people have guns. Why should we let them have ideas?  (Vladimir Lenin)

> The better I get to know men, the more I find myself loving dogs.  (Charles deGaulle)

> We cannot always build the future for our youth, but we can build our youth for the future.  (Franklin D. Roosevelt)

Comment: Good job @JuanTomas ! I'll accept Beastly's answer since he gave the relationship the first.